# Enabling Level 2 WebDAV on nginx

Tags: nginx, webdav

When I mount my nginx WebDAV server as a macOS volume, it is mounted as read-only.

I've read the suggestions on [this page](https://www.geddy.au/recipes/webdav/nginx-webdav-server) but they use the `more_set_input_headers` which is not available on my `nginx-full` Debian package.

I've tried adding the nginx repository and adding the module manually with:

```
curl -fsSL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg
ano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list

# added
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] https://nginx.org/packages/debian/ bookworm nginx

apt-get update
apt-get install nginx-plus-module-headers-more # not found
```

Apparently this module is only available with the commercial nginx Plus package.

The WebDAV server works as expected if I use Cadaver but I'd like to mount it as a Finder volume (as well as a Windows network drive).

1. Is there any way I can accomplish this behavior with the regular nginx distribution?
2. Will I have the same problem if I switch to Apache?

Thanks.

Comment: Just install `nginx-extras`. It has **Headers More** module.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module that seems to be what you are looking for from Homepage: https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module
Try:

sudo apt install libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter